# Duplicate Page Content for SEO

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, seo, iis-6

My SEO tool is telling me that https://example.com has duplicate content with those pages. 
URL(s) with Duplicate Page Titles

https://example.com/Employment/default.aspx

https://example.com/employment/Default.aspx

https://example.com/Employment/Default.aspx

i have IIS6 and i used a rewrite lowercase rule to solve this, the problem is solved on the browser and all URLS are lowercase now but i still have duplicate pages and my SEO tool is still showing the duplicates
i want to write a rule on IIS to get rid of those duplicates
PS: https://example.com is the same page as https://example.com/Employment/Default.aspx

Comment: Are you fixing the original links as well? Does the rewrite cause a 301 Redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the content on all pages is the same and this is, in fact, the same page (with different URLs), then rel=canonical is your best bet. This will tell Googlebot (and Bing, etc) that Default.aspx is really the same as default.aspx, and to attribute any search relevancy you receive with Default.aspx to default.aspx.

On proper canonical tags here:

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en

Alternatively (and perhaps to be used in conjunction with), there are 301 permanent redirects.

This accomplishes effectively the same as the canonical, but permanently redirects visitors from Default.aspx to default.aspx, Googlebot included. Again, search relevancy will be passed from the former to the latter link.

More on implementing below:

http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpredirect